# Logo not centered inside fixed menu when scrolling down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I bought a template that has a logo in the middle, but when I scroll down the logo moves and isn't centered anymore.

[Example](http://codeboxr.com/themedemo/foodie/html/about.html)

I set position absolute and added left: auto, right: auto but still it is not centered. Why is that?

My page is exactly the same except I added:

```
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: auto;
right: auto;
```

on the sticked logo and:

```
position: absolute;
top: -30px;
left: auto;
right: auto;
```

on the main logo (not scrolled down).

Comment: The img is wider than the `.main-logo` container. If you use `.cbx-header .stick .cbx-logo .main-logo img { max-width: 100% }` the img will reduce in size to fit the container.

Comment: In the given link, the logo is in center of the screen

Comment: If you want to make always to be center, Give a specific with to the image or to the parent. And in css just make `.class-name{margin: 0 auto}`.

Comment: Thanks @Turnip that works for a relative element, but I positioned mine absolute because of a longer logo that falls over the menu. How can I do it that way?

Comment: Which logo are you talking about? I only see one logo in the header.

Comment: Yeah this is an example, I can't just add the actual logo online yet. It's exactly the same code, except mine is positioned absolute, so your solution does not work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this css

```
.cbx-header .stick .cbx-logo {
left: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

}

Comment: Wasn't expecting this simple solution to work but it did! Thanks.